# is it possible to create azure function from ARM template and let it get the code from zip file stored in azure storage?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

is it possible to create azure function from ARM template and let it get the code from zip file or Code related files stored in azure storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use [Run-From-Zip](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84). See here for details.

All you have to do in your template is set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP` to the sas URL of your zip file in Storage.

Do note that the sas needs to remain valid as long as the app needs to run. It is not a 'deploy time only' URL.